# While Converting Object to JSON Error :com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am trying to convert `List<Object>` into `JSON` format using `ObjectMapper`. I tried like below But I am getting exception i.e.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:

```
    public List<ClientRT> callSP() throws IOException { 

            List<Object> crt=crtRepo.roomtype(60);          

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String json=mapper.writeValueAsString(crt);

            //ClientRT obj=mapper.readValue(json,ClientRT.class);

            List<ClientRT> obj=mapper.readValue(json,mapper.getTypeFactory()
                                                           .constructCollectionLikeType(List.class,ClientRT.class));
            return obj;
        }
```

**ClientRT Class**

```
public class ClientRT { 

    public Integer res_nclient_room_type_id;    
    public String res_sclient_rt_desc;
    public String  res_sclient_rt_name;
    public String res_sclient_rt_code;

    //getter setter

    public ClientRT() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClientRT [res_nclient_room_type_id=" + res_nclient_room_type_id + ", res_sclient_rt_desc="
                + res_sclient_rt_desc + ", res_sclient_rt_name=" + res_sclient_rt_name + ", res_sclient_rt_code="
                + res_sclient_rt_code + "]";
    }
}
```

**Expecting Result In JSON**

```
[  
  { "res_nclient_room_type_id":1 ,   
    "res_sclient_rt_desc": "FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM",
    "res_sclient_rt_name":"FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM" ,
    "res_sclient_rt_code":"050" 
 },

]
```

**Exception**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.spacestudy.model.ClientRT` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[[1,"TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED","TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED","000"],[2,"FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM","FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM","050"],[3,"FACILITIES - UNDEFINED PURPOSE","FACILITIES - UNDEFINED PURPOSE","060"],[4,"FACILITIES - UNFINISHED AREA","FACILITIES - UNFINISHED AREA","070"],[5,"CLASSROOM/LECTURE HALL","CLASSROOM/LECTURE HALL","110"],[6,"CLASSROOM SERVICE","CLASSROOM SERVICE","115"],[7,"CLASSROOM STORAGE","CLASSROOM STORAGE","116"],[8,"CLASSROOM KITCHEN","CLASSROOM KITCHEN","119"],[9,"CLA"[truncated 8500 chars]; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Can any one please tell me how I can resolve this Exception?

Comment: Could you post `ClientRT` class? And an example of the json. Seems like you are passing incorrect json to Jackson

Comment: I added class and sample json

Answer (score 0):

The json you are passing to Jackson is incorrect.

Instead of passing to Jackson this Json:

```
[  
  { "res_nclient_room_type_id":1 ,   
    "public String res_sclient_rt_desc": "FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM",
    "public String  res_sclient_rt_name":"FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM" ,
    "public String res_sclient_rt_code":"050" 
 }
]
```

Try with this one (remove `public String` from the json):

```
[  
  { "res_nclient_room_type_id":1 ,   
    "res_sclient_rt_desc": "FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM",
    "res_sclient_rt_name":"FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM" ,
    "res_sclient_rt_code":"050" 
  }
]
```

Jackson can't parse the json because it can't find the corresponding Java field in class `ClientRT`. Remove `public String` from the json and leave only the name of the field of class `ClientRT`.

Comment: only name of field in class giving error without data type

Comment: @SpringUser You have to remove the data type from the Json, not from the Java class. I edited the answer

Comment: No problem, the only thing that's important is that you understand the error.

Comment: that json is my expected result which I wan't but my error is still there

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct json to Jackson? I tried and your code works for me with the correct json.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are asking about ` correct json to jackson` . are you talking about `List<ClientRT> obj=mapper.readValue(json,mapper.getTypeFactory().....` this`json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191896/discussion-between-amicoderozer-and-springuser).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by amicoderozer above, you need to remove the data type of the fields of class `ClientRT` from the json and not from the class.

Comment: sorry I wrongly added public string in json.  but that is my expected result

Comment: Can you please specify what type of objects does `List<Object> crt` contain?

Comment: I am calling stored function from postgresql i.e. roomtype(60) i.e. simple select * from ClientRoomType

Comment: The objects in the list `List<Object> crt` should be `ClientRT` objects, else Jackson will throw a `MismatchedInputException`.

Comment: crt contains ClientRT objects only . but i am trying to convert object to json

Comment: Can you print the json that you're getting in the following line?

`String json=mapper.writeValueAsString(crt);`